# rails 3 + ajax: what is simplest way to embed variable-length report html from my rails app onto another webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

My app collects data reports that our users want to embed onto their own webpages.

The report is a short daily activity report... but the report length varies based upon the particular data that day, so a fixed-iframe will not work... one day the report might have 10 lines, the next day the same report might have 100 lines.

Currently, they have to put a huge iframe on their webpage that attempts to be larger than the biggest report... but that's hit or miss.

I need to offer a better way that 
a) works independently of the size of the html data that is returned, and 
b) still allows us to control the display of the report via CSS on our server (eg, does not require them to add a our stylesheet to their website)

The info I've seen using ajax with rails -- including an earlier question I asked -- seems to assume the destination page has an iframe...

But an iframe will not resize to fit the data, right?

**Not having done ajax before, I'm looking for the simplest solution to embed this kind of variable-length content from my rails3 app to remote webpages.**

suppose, for example my app has a url/route/view:
http://example.com/dailyreport/customer_key=ABCDEFGHIJ
that currently returns a very simple css-styled html page with that customer's daily report:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/reports.css">
</head>
<body>
  REPORT IS DISPLAYED HERE
</body>
```

I'd appreciate any info on how to transition from our current fixed-iframe non-ajax approach to an approach **(presumably ajax? without iframe?)** that handles arbitrary-length data coming from our app.